# Parsing a character string condition in R

Tags: r, string, if-statement

I have a character string and wants R to treat it as a logical condition to be used in an if loop.

```
condition <- "df$a > 2"
```

How can I force R to treat condition as a logical so that this if statement works?

```
if(condition){
  print(df$a)
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're looping over, but if your data.frame has multiple rows, you will have multiple conditions here (which doesn't make sense for control flow with `if (cond) ...`)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `parse` and `eval`. For example:

```
condition <- "2 + 2"

if (eval(parse(text = condition)) > 1) {
  print('true')
}

[1] "true"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use parse(text = condition) to parse the string to an expression. Then use eval to evaluate the expression:

```
a <- 4
condition <- "a > 2"

if (eval(parse(text = condition))) {
  print(a)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be simply achieved with a call to eval and parse functions from base R

```
if(eval(parse(text = condition)){
  print(df$a)
}
```