# Using a string as the condition of an if statement in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, eval

I am trying to create a function that takes the condition of an if statement as a string and returns it as a boolean to use in an if statement. Once I have the boolean, I want to be able to return `$body` if is true.

The logic would look something similar to the below:

```php
public function ifStatement($query, $body) {
    if (eval($query)) {
       return $body;
    }
}
```

So when using the function, the output would look something like this where if the condition is evaluated and if the condition is true, it would return the `$body`, but if it's false it would return nothing.

```php
ifStatement('true', 'Hello World!');         // Returns 'Hello World!'
ifStatement('false', 'Hello World!');        // Returns nothing
ifStatement('0 == 0', 'Hello World!');       // Returns 'Hello World!'
ifStatement('0 == 1', 'Hello World!');       // Returns nothing
```

The primary reason I am looking for something like this is so because I am creating a template engine where I want to be able to pass if statements and other logic statements into php as a string and have it return the appropriate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using eval to evaluate the string like that will not work because it is not valid php syntax.  Instead of using `eval($query)`, try using `eval("return $query;")` that way you are actually returning the value as a boolean instead of using the string itself in the condition of the if statement.

So the revised code would look something like this:

```php
function ifStatement($query, $body) {

    $condition = eval("return $query;");
    
    if ($condition) return $body;
    return;
}
```

In that new function you are able to take in whatever condition you want and it will be evaluated as a boolean. So then the resulting outputs would like like this:

```php
print ifStatement("true", "This is true");
    # Returns "This is true"

print ifStatement("false", "This is false");
    # Returns nothing

print ifStatement("1 == 1", "1 is 1");
    # Returns "1 is 1"

print ifStatement("1 == 2", "1 is not 1");
    # Returns nothing
```

---

#### Adding a false condition

If you wanted to go a step further, you could modify the function a little bit more to include what is returned in the event that the condition is false.  All you would need to do is add a new optional param which would be what is returned if the condition is false.  It would look like this:

```php
function ifStatement($query, $trueBody, $falseBody = "") {

    $condition = eval("return $query;");
    
    if ($condition) return $trueBody;
    else return $falseBody;
}
```

With the outputs looking like this:

```php
print ifStatement("true", "This is true", "This is false");
    # Returns "This is true"

print ifStatement("false", "This is true", "This is false");
    # Returns "This is false"

print ifStatement("1 == 1", "1 is 1", "1 is not 1");
    # Returns "1 is 1"

print ifStatement("1 == 2", "1 is 1", "1 is not 1");
    # Returns "1 is not 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `$string1` and `$string2` as true false boolean not as string.And then check it.It works!

```
function ifStatement($query, $body) {
    if ($query) {
     return $body;
    }
}

$string1 = true;
$string2 = false;
ifStatement($string1, 'Hello World!');        //Returns True
ifStatement($string2, 'Hello World!');               //Return False
```

**Output**

```
Hello World!      //Outputs only first one which is true.
```

Comment: Umm... This still won't work because you changed nothing about the code and add a break.  This still doesn't fix my problem because regardless  of the small little change you made to the code, the underlying problem that a string will always return true in the if statement still persists.

Comment: Excatly what do you want can you explain because your question was not much explanatory

Comment: How can I make it work How can I take a string and make it work in the if statement.

Comment: It hasn't changed?

Comment: Okay it still doesn't help.  The true and false are just examples, I need to be able to take a string and make it compatible with an if statement

Comment: Please be clear meaning of   compatible with an if statement means what give an example.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if you found the answer to your question, but i think it would be beneficial for futur reader (as me), to answer this subject.
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484607/parsing-a-character-string-condition-in-r) explain how you can use the `eval(parse())` combinaison to achieve what you were trying to do.

Hope this helped

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My answer redirect new reader to a subject were they can find the solution to the autor  problem. How can I be clearer than that ?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33557049)